# SQL Server Database deployed to a server to be used in a web app:

Tags: mysql, database

I am developing a web app...and instead of creating the web apps database using MySQL Databases from the provider.  Can I just use the SQL Server Database that I can add to the site in Visual Studio?  I vaguely remember this not working and I had to result to using the providers MySQL Database through the phpmyadmin.

I go this error.

> The system cannot find the file specified
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Source Error:

Line 18:         {
Line 19:             SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["userDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
Line 20:             conn.Open();
Line 21:             string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where Username='" + TextBoxUN.Text + "'";
Line 22:             SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);

Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\motorcity3d.com\www\Registration.aspx.cs    Line: 20

Stack Trace:

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) +1431
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1085
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +70
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +964
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +109
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1529
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +156
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +258
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +312
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +202
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +413
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +128
   Registration.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\motorcity3d.com\www\Registration.aspx.cs:20
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +106
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3785

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3062.0

Comment: Your question is a bit thin, but the answer is that your PHP application should be able to use any database provided that it has a driver for that database.

Comment: Oh Yeah, Sorry,  I am developing in asp.net using C#.

Comment: I'm about to deploy so I'll see if it works.